# How can I create dynamic destination files name based on what is filtered?

Tags: syslog-ng

For example if in my log line appears something like that [xxx], I must put this message in a file with a name starting as xxx.log
And if the message changes and appears [xxy] I must create a new log file named as xxy.log
How can I do that in a syslog-ng config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this way to resolve mi problem.

```
parser p_apache {
    csv-parser(columns("MY.ALGO", "MY.MOSTRAR", "MY.OTRA")
         delimiters("|")
         );
};

destination d_file {
    file("/var/log/syslog-ng/$YEAR-$MONTH/$DAY/messages-${MY.ALGO:-nouser}.log");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

to filter for specific messages, you can use filter expressions in syslog-ng:
You can use regular expressions in the filter as well.
To use the results of the match in the filename, try using a named pattern in the filter expression:

```
filter f_myfilter {message("(?<name>pattern)");};
```

Then you can use the named match in the destination template:

```
destination d_file {
    file ("/var/log/${name}.log");
};
```

Let me know if it works, I haven't had the time to test it.

Comment: Is something wrong with the pattern, y replace my previus config using this line message("(?[*name*]pattern)"); but I get an error parsing filter expression.

Comment: It's possible that named patterns are supported only in rewrite rules, I'll try to check this sometime

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the answer here.

Eg: I have a file name **access2018-10-21.log** for source so my access log source file entry becomes

```
file("/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp13/tomcat-7.0.62/logs/access[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9].log" follow_freq(1) flags(no-parse));
```